# Mutually referencing nested classes in C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes, incomplete-type

I have a number of situations where I need to mutually reference nested classes e.g.

```
class C1;
class C2;
// class C2::S; // not allowed by the standard    

template <class T> class R
{
  T* t = nullptr; // The only use of T as a data member is a T*
};

class C1
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:
    R <C2::S> r; // Fails to compile because C2 is an incomplete type
  };
};

class C2
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:
    R <C1::S> r;
  };
};
```

This fails because C2 is incomplete and at the point where it is used and so C2::S is not known to the compiler.

The question is in two parts:

1. Is there a way to make this work in C++23 ?
2. If not, is there, or has there been, any proposal to the C++ committee which would help?

There are a couple of 'obvious' solutions but I'm hoping not to have to use them:

- Flatten the structure so there's no nesting. The actual examples I have are much more complex and this would make the code unreadable.
- Use void* and then cast as necessary.

I was expecting to be able to use a dummy class in place of C2::S and then map it to C2::S before  using it but it appears you can't declare a class and then redefine it with 'using', e.g. the following doesn't work:

```
class Z; // Z first defined as a class
class C1
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:
    R<Z> r;
  };
};
class C2
{...}
using Z = C2::S; // Redefinition error (defining Z as a typedef vs. a class)
```

I've also tried with templates e.g.

```
template <class T> class TC1
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:
  R <typename T::S> r;
  };
};

template <class T> class TC2
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:

  R <typename T::S> r;

  };
};

using C1 = TC1 <TC2 <C1>>; // Error: C1 undeclared (or not in scope)
```

Regarding additions to the standard, I realize that allowing the use of incomplete types would never be acceptable as it would cause a lot of complexity e.g. in specifying what could and could not be used, or trying to define when different partially-defined versions of the same class are compatible or not.

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: `R<void> r;` in the declaration and then cast to the `C2::S*` later in the definition where used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the usual situation where people wish they could write

```
class A::B;
```

instead of defining **`A`**: you just want to have the nested classes refer to each other.  That means that ordinary forward declarations work:

```
class C1
{
public:
  class S;
};

class C2
{
public:
  class S
  {
  public:
    R <C1::S> r;
  };
};

class C1::S
{
public:
  R <C2::S> r;
};
```

Obviously this depends on `R` not needing its template argument to be a complete type.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this appears to work. I had assumed that at the point where C1::S is used, C1 would have to be completely defined and that would require S to be defined. However I now see that the specification says that a type is only incomplete if its size cannot be determined, which doesn't apply if S isn't inlined.

Comment: @Rob190 I'm not sure what "inlining" S has to do with anything: For once, templates are usually "inlined" because their implementation is usually visible at the point of instantiation (it's in the header); also, S's size indeed cannot be determined here.

Comment: I meant 'inlining' in the sense of fully defining S within the definitions of C1 and C2. Maybe that's the wrong use of the term.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a forward declaration like so

```
template <class T>
class R
{
    T *t = nullptr; // The only use of T as a data member is a T*
};

class C1
{
public:
    class S;
};

class C2
{
public:
    class S
    {
    public:
        R<C1::S> r;
    };
};

class C1::S
{
public:
    R<C2::S> r;
};
```